# Making a turtle plot a series of points

Tags: python, regression

The Python guide I'm following has this exercise:

[image]

(sorry for using a screenshot, I couldn't format the special characters)

`labdata.txt` is a series of lines each consisting of two integers, so if this is just about making the turtle go to a series of points where x is the first integer and y is the second one, I'm in fact completely capable of doing it and have done it before for another exercise; I can probably also manage to scale the window just fine. However, as I barely have any formal education in maths, I don't understand the formulas and the explanation provided in the guide isn't really helping.

This is my previous programme, by the way, which just makes the turtle draw a picture based on instructions from a text file:

```
import turtle

def instruct(aturtle,alist):
    if alist[0] == 'UP':
        aturtle.up()
    elif alist[0] == 'DOWN':
        aturtle.down()
    else:
        alist = [int(item) for item in alist]
        aturtle.setposition(alist[0],alist[1])

def draw_file(aturtle,afile):
    aline = afile.readline()
    while aline:
        info = aline.split()
        instruct(aturtle,info)
        aline = afile.readline()

def main():
    my_file = open('mystery.txt','r')

    wn = turtle.Screen()
    wn.bgcolor('lightcyan')
    wn.setworldcoordinates(-400,-400,400,400)

    steklovata = turtle.Turtle()
    steklovata.color('darkslategray')
    steklovata.shapesize(0.1)
    steklovata.speed(100)

    draw_file(steklovata,my_file)

    wn.exitonclick()

main()
```

Thanks in advance!

Comment: You haven't asked an explicit question... but I suspect the first thing you should try to do is compute `x hat` and `y hat` as described in the guide.

Comment: The problem is that _I don't understand what's described in the guide_.

Comment: It's describing how to find a straight line that _best fits_ a set of points that _don't_ lie on a straight line.

Comment: Check out the figures on this page: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_regression

Comment: I've just skimmed through it and I think I'm getting a better idea of it now, thank you. I'll probably edit the question to add what I understand after a more in-depth read if I need any further help.